# Why doesn't this .htaccess code for a clean URL work?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make a a URL that currently reads:

`www.site.com/events/event.php?event_id=_n_`
(where n is a number, naturally)

Read simply:

```
www.site.com/events/
```

I have the following code in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^events/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ event.php?event_id=$1
```

But it doesn't seem to make any difference, regardless of whether I put the file in the root or the `events` directory. Any ideas?

Comment: If you make it `www.site.com/events/` how will you get `event_id` in your `event.php`?

Comment: this .htaccess is in root directory or in events directory?

Comment: Ah, would that not work? would it have to be `www.site.com/events/event`?

Comment: @Dracris I've tried it in both, makes no difference

Comment: Your URL must be formed like `/events/number`. That's what you basically wrote down in your `.htaccess`. And put `[L]` after `event.php?event_id=$1`

Comment: and if n is number put only `^events/([0-9]+)$`

Comment: @user3181236: You can get `www.site.com/event/10` where 10 is your `event_id`.

Comment: Ok, well, regardless of what the output should look like (I'm happy with `site.com/events/_n_`), it simply isn't doing that. I have added [L] as @GuyT suggests

Comment: @user3181236 you're sure you're using an URL like `<a href="/events/10">event</a>` and you've put the `.htaccess` file in the root?

Comment: I suspect OP is using `/event.php?event_id=10` URL and would like to see it redirected to `/events/10`.

Comment: That's also what I think he's really asking, otherwise his URL would already did the job ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place these 2 rules in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/events/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /events/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /event\.php\?event_id=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ event.php?event_id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I'm afraid that makes no difference again. Could some server setting be preventing it from working? I have some 301 redirects in there that are working fine.

Comment: Yes they could make difference. This rule must be places as first rule right at top of your .htaccess.

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess and what error are you getting? Details please?

Comment: It's in the root, and I'm not getting an error _per se_, it's just not changing the URL - it simply remains the same.

Comment: So `.htaccess` and `event.php` are at same level? What is the full URL tat you are entering in your browser? And place your latest .htaccess in your question.

Comment: no, event.php is in /events. I'm entering `http://www.site.com/events/event.php?event_id=1`

Comment: Oh ok that's the reason. See update above, this goes in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/events/.htaccess`

Comment: Ok, that works! Thank you. It does break the page though, I guess I need to use absolute links to stylesheets etc?

Comment: Yes use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`. OR else try adding this in your page's header: `<base href="/" />`.

Comment: I've just noticed that this makes the url www.site.com/events/events/10 - is there a way to make it just www.site.com/events/10?

Comment: Thank you. If I wanted to undo this and revert to the normal url, how would I do it?

Comment: Just comment out the first rule that has `%{THE_REQUEST}`.